# How to get the URL property in a Promoted Links list

Tags: 2013, javascript, development, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I have added a new "Promoted Link" list which comes with some built-in fields such as :

- Title
- Link Location

I am trying to query this list using REST end point, and dynamically build my view , as follow:-

```
$.ajax({
     url: "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Useful Links')/items?$select=Title,LinkLocation&$orderby=Title asc",
     method: "GET",   
     headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
     success: function (data) {
        if(data.d.results.length>0){

            var items=data.d.results;
            for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++){        
                    var nurl = items[i].LinkLocation;
                    var ntitle = items[i].Title.toString();

html+="<ul unselectable='on'><li class='ms-comm-adminLinksListItem' unselectable='on'><a href=" + nurl + " target='_blank' unselectable='on'>"+ ntitle + "</a></li></ul>";
      }
            html+="</ul></div>";
            $("#inserthere").after(html);
        }
     },
     error: function (data) {       
     }
    });
```

The problem I am facing is that the `items[i].LinkLocation` will have the following value "`[Object]`" instead of showing the real link location url value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to drill down into the LinkLocation using:

```
item[i].LinkLocation.Url
```

As each link is an object consists of Url and Description.